# Passing a List to Enum as parameter

Tags: java, enums

```
public enum Character
{
LAURA("Laura", Item.SANDWICH,0.0f), SALLY("Sally", Item.CRISPS,0.1f), 
ANDY("Andy", Item.DRINK,0.2f), ALEX("Alex", null,0.3f);

private String description;
private Item item;
private float probability;
ArrayList<Item> itemsLaura = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Item> itemsSally = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Item> itemsAndy = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Item> itemsAlex = new ArrayList<>();
/**
 * Constructor initialising description,item and probability.
 */
private Character(String desc, Item it,float moveProbability)
{
    itemsLaura.add(Item.SANDWICH);
    itemsSally.add(Item.CRISPS);
    itemsAndy.add(Item.DRINK);
    itemsAlex.add(null);
    item = it;
    probability =moveProbability;
}
```

I have the above enum of Character, I need to change it so instead of each character having one Item they have a list of Item. How would I do that?

I have created ArrayLists for each character but I don't know how to pass them as parameters to the enum Character.

Comment: Use `Arrays.asList()`.

Comment: How would I use Arrays.asList()

Comment: Read the documentation.

Comment: I still don't understand what is meant to do

Comment: It's just a streamlined way to initialize a list.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a `List<Item>`, you can have a variable amount of `Item` by using varargs, but first you should swap `moveProbability` to be the second argument (as the varargs parameter must be the last element).  Your signature will end up like this:

```
private Character(String desc, float moveProbability, Item... items) {
    ...
}
```

You can then change:

```
private Item item;
```

to

```
private Item[] items;
```

and have the following within your constructor:

```
this.items = items;
```

This will allow your enum values to take multiple `Item`s:

```
LAURA("Laura", 0.0f, Item.SANDWICH, Item.DRINK, Item.CRISPS)
```